# how to get the colors on the screen better then get pixel? (c++)

Tags: visual-c++, performance, pixel

i made a program that uses the colors of pixels from the screen but getpixel is slow so is there a better way to find the color of pixels. i don't care if i get the full screen or one pixel at a time but the main thing is speed.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on what you need to do. If you only *need* one pixel, then use GetPixel--it may be slow, but who cares when you only need one? If you are trying to capture a whole region of the screen, though, then there are screen capture APIs you can use. Once you have the screen capture, you can pick out whatever pixels you want.

Answer (score 0):

[BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28VS.85%29.aspx) is pretty fast.  It also allows you to specify a region to be copied, so you don't have to copy pixels you don't want.